# Flex add and subtract six months from now

Tags: apache-flex

Here is the code I am trying

```
        public static const millisecondsPerDay:int = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
        var sixMonthsInMilis:int = 182 * millisecondsPerDay;
        var sixMonthsInTheFuture:Date = new Date();
        sixMonthsInTheFuture.setTime(sixMonthsInTheFuture.getTime() + sixMonthsInMilis );
        var sixMonthsInThePast:Date = new Date();
        sixMonthsInThePast.setTime(sixMonthsInThePast.getTime() - sixMonthsInMilis);
```

The one thats meant to be in the past is a few days in the future, the other a few days in the past. A far cry from the 6 months I am after

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var today:Date = new Date();
today.setMonth(today.getMonth() + 6);
var sixMonthsInTheFuture:Date = today;
var anotherToday:Date = new Date();
anotherToday.setMonth(anotherToday.getMonth() - 6);
var sixMonthsInThePast:Date = anotherToday;

trace(sixMonthsInTheFuture);
trace(sixMonthsInThePast);
```

For me, this returns

> Mon May 28 14:03:32 GMT+0530 2012
>   Sat May 28 14:03:32 GMT+0530 2011

Which seems fair enough, right?

Answer (score 0):

Um... var

```
var now:Date = new Date();
now.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 6);
var sixMonthsInTheFuture:Date = now;
var now:Date = new Date();
now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 6);
var sixMonthsInThePast:Date = now;
```

Not sure if this would work 100%, as I'm not sure if Flex does date overflowing, (Like, would September + 6 be January the next year?), some languages do. Try it out

Apparently setMonth also takes a second paramater, Day, which is day number between 1 and 31, so some more ifs to check date and if it's more than the largest day of the new month etc., but this is the general idea